# Firebase app not being configured

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, xcode8

This randomly started happening and I cannot get passed it. My app crashes on launch with this in the debug area.

> 2016-10-29 14:31:57.606 gigMe[2285:73317] Firebase automatic screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics setScreenName:setScreenClass:] to set the screen name or override the default screen class name. To disable automatic screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseAutomaticScreenReportingEnabled to NO in the Info.plist
>
> 2016-10-29 14:31:57.783 gigMe[2285]  [Firebase/Core][I-COR000003] The default Firebase app has not yet been configured. Add [FIRApp configure] to your application initialization. Read more: gives google address that i cant post on here
>
> 2016-10-29 14:31:57.911 gigMe[2285:73317] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FIRAppNotConfigured', reason: 'Failed to get default FIRDatabase instance. Must call FIRApp.configure() before using FIRDatabase.' *** First throw call stack:

I really dont understand this at all because i havent messed with anything that has to do with the database and this is my `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    print("wtf")
    FIRApp.configure()

    return true
}
```

im not getting anything printed in the debugger either. anyone know what is going on?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This is not **`FIRApp.configure()`** error. You might be declaring a global variable with some class function in any of your class, like

```
class viewCon : UIViewController{

let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference() // or a Storage reference
    // This might be the error
   }
```

The reason why this happens is because , you are trying to initialise a variable with a class function/property which might not even be configured as of yet. So try this:-

```
 class viewCon : UIViewController{

    let ref : FIRDatabaseReference! 
       // This might be the error or a Storage reference

     override func viewDidLoad(){

       super.viewDidLoad()
       ref =  FIRDatabase.database().reference()
      }
  }
```

To support above theory, try using breakpoints on `let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()` and `FIRApp.configure()`, and see which one gets called first. If `let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()` is called first , you are bound to have this error, as **`ref`** is trying to access `FIRDatabase` class, which hasn't been configured yet..

Comment: Thanks Dravidian.  Note: there's a typo in your, otherwise terrific, answer.  Capital R needed in `var ref : FIRDatabaseReference!`

Comment: Thanks!! Dravidian